# 'Flicker' NLA Strips through Python?

Tags: python, nla-editor

I am working on a project where I have a few hundred pipes represented as curves that exist in 3 states:

1. Visible and Static
2. Animated (Scaling Curve depth to 0 from `n`)
3. Invisible and Static (Existing with a depth of 0)

In different shots, I need certain pipes to be visible, invisible or animated. I am using the NLA editor to toggle the animation and visibility state of the curve (frame 0: Muted = state 1, frame: 0: Not Muted = State 2, final frame: Muted = state 3) instead of toggling the visibility of the object itself.

It has been extremely tedious to find and toggle the mute setting for tracks as I go, as well when I need an object to change from state 1->3 or 3->1, I have to double click the Mute checkbox in the NLA editor at the correct frame. Below is an example of the steps to produce this.

[image: Example of workflow]

What I am looking for is a way to **flicker** * the 'Mute' state of a given list of NLA strips.

* *By flicker, I mean to toggle the Mute state twice, so if it were to start as False, the state would change from False->True->False, or on the other hand starting as True, True->False->True.)*

I found [this Operator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqmOV.jpg) while playing with the system, and using the operator itself works in the editor (I use the Spacebar Search menu to find it) but I would like to either invoke this operator through a python script, or call a function with a similar effect through a script.

Please let me know if anything needs further clarification - I understand that this is a stranger use case for the NLA Editor.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way I have discovered to do this through existing operators which handles **ALL** animations available in the NLA Editor is to use the following Operators (I bound them to my Quick Access menu:

[Select All](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.0/bpy.ops.nla.html#bpy.ops.nla.select_all) - Found under the Header Menu -> Select -> All

[Toggle Channel Settings](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.0/bpy.ops.anim.html#bpy.ops.anim.channels_setting_toggle) - Do this twice

I'd like to handle this with a script, but I will solve that later. Ideally I'd like to be able to be more selective instead of simply doing ALL or NONE (aside from filtering Collections) but this works for me for now.

Also worth noting - **be wary and save your file** before doing this on many objects, I had a few hard crashes after successfully doing this operation.